# Python - difference in speed between command line and browser

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am timing the execution of a script by subracting one `time.time()` from another one, the first at the start and the second one at the end of the code.

I realize that when I run the script from command line, the execution is much faster (0.09s) than if I request it through the browser (0.14s). I repeated it several times and the time is always in that range.

Can anyone help to understand why it takes much more when requested through the browser.

One difference I realized so far is that if I request the script throught the browser, `sys.path` doesn't contain the current directory (in which I placed an empty `__init__.py` file), while if I run it via command line, the current directory is cointained in `sys.path`

EDIT:

I had some print statements inside a function called by worker threads running in parallel (my script is fetching some files in parallel)

I verified that:
1) when the print statements are there, the script is executed much faster via command line than via the browser
2) when I remove the print statements, the script is executed via browser as fast as it is via command line

any explanation for that?

(if you are wondering which Python version I am using, it's 2.6.6)

Comment: How are you calling it with the browser?

Comment: just by typing the address http://www.domain.com/pythonscriptsdir/scriptname.py?someparams=value

Comment: So CGI? What does the script look like?

Comment: the script creates 3 threads, each of them requesting a file via http and parsing it

Comment: are there other ways to call the script via the browser?

Comment: Maybe if you posted your code we could help you.

Comment: @DanieleB: WSGI and FastCGI are two that I know off the top of my head.

Comment: @DanieleB: Or a server written in Python that has the script embedded in the server code, or…

Comment: There are many possibilities here. One is that the server itself is using CPU or other resources (since it seems like your script is probably network-bound anyway) while it's running your script. Another is that when you run it repeatedly from the command-line, more stuff gets cached. It's also possible that the server is not using a .pyc file, and the command line is.

Comment: considering I am using these scripts as web services (and not webpages), and I can call the scripts whichever way I want as long as they have a URL, what do you think is the best and neatest solution for optimizing their speed?

Comment: I noticed by calling the script via command line, the .pyc file gets created. I don't know if that influences its speed.

Comment: I added an EDIT to my question: I had some print statements inside a function called by worker threads running in parallel. I verified that: 1) when the print statements are there, the script is executed much faster via command line than via the browser 2) when I remove the print statements, the script is executed via browser as fast as it is via command line. Any explanations?

Comment: Print statements in CGI are data that needs to be transmitted over the network, but print statements locally are data that just needs to go to the screen. You can't really compare these 2 scenarios for performance.

Comment: doesn't the webserver wait until the end of the script to send the data to the client? does CGI behaves differently to WSGI in this?